# copy everything after a string into a different column in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have some columns in a data frame that look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(act=c("DEC S/N, de 21/06/2006",
                        "DEC S/N, de 05/06/2006",
                         "DEC S/N, de 21/06/2006; MP 542, de 12/08/2011; LEI 12.678, de 25/06/2012"), adj=NA)
```

I would like to copy everything after the first ; (MP 542, de 12/08/2011; LEI 12.678, de 25/06/2012) in the column 'act', into the column 'adj'. Ideally, removing the space that would be left at the star of the cut-off string. All other cells, this is, where the strings in column 'act' do not have a ; should be left NA in column 'adj'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str_match` from `stringr` :

```
df <- data.frame(act=c("DEC S/N, de 21/06/2006",
                       "DEC S/N, de 05/06/2006",
                       "DEC S/N, de 21/06/2006; MP 542, de 12/08/2011; LEI 12.678, de 25/06/2012"), adj=NA)
df %>% mutate(adj = str_match(act, "[^;]*;(.*)")[,2])
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot! 
Just for the record, I'm doing it on a large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. If somebody finds it useful here's how it worked:
```
SpatialPolygonsDataFrame@data <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame@data %>% mutate(adj = str_match(act, "[^;]*;(.*)")[,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr::str_extract` -

```
df$adj <- stringr::str_extract(df$act, '(?<=;\\s)(.*)')
df$adj
#[1] NA   NA    "MP 542, de 12/08/2011; LEI 12.678, de 25/06/2012"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  extract(act, 'adj', '; (.*)', remove = FALSE)
```

or even try:

```
df %>%
  separate(act, c('act1', 'adj'), '; ', 
           extra = 'merge', fill = 'right', remove = FALSE)
```